# How to get a working gcc 4.9 on an ARM system

Tags: compiling, gcc, compiler

I have an ARM system with ubuntu 14.0.4 and I need a working `gcc` 4.8 on it. I was sad to learn that according to http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages.gz the is no `gcc-4.9` package for ARM, but only `gcc-4.9-base`. After installing it there was no `gcc` binary.

So I started to build it myself (with the existing gcc-4.8). The configure script is a broken mess; several the `make` failed because of missing dependencies that were not checked by `configure`. Solvable, but finally I ran into

```
In file included from ./bconfig.h:3:0,
             from ../.././gcc/inchash.c:21:
./auto-host.h:2359:16: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 #define rlim_t long
                ^
```

This problem can be found a few times with search engines, but either as a bug that should already be fixed, sometimes to be solved with configure option, but non of those worked for me.

Question: What should I do to get gcc 4.9:

- continue with building it myself (if yes, how?)
- install a binary package (where do I get it for armgf?)
- use the debian package (yes, debian has an arm binary package!), but I'm afraid of future problems with such an essential package from a different distribution
- What else do you suggest?

Comment: Did you try the [toochain-r ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r)? it looks like it [provides armhf binaries](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing Debian instead of Ubuntu. A Debian version doesn't get released until it's tested on all platforms, while the Ubuntu community seems completely focused on x86 and amd64.

My recommendation for future readers: Don't waste time on debugging Ubuntu problems on different platforms, switch to Debian or do your own Yocto oder Buildroot thing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the ./configure script was wrong and made clashing definitions into some of the generated header files or incorrectly set some of the HAVE_* macros.

This indicates configuration problems. You should check the documentation in the INSTALL directory to find out what options you need to specify to make it compile.

Building cross compilers can be tricky.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wasn't talking about cross compilers. Everything is native. But native *ARM*. I solved the issue by saying goodbye to Ubuntu. Using Ubuntu on anything but x86 and amd64 is simply a pain. The development process is mono-platform. A Debian version doesn't get released until it's tested on all platforms. Could be that Ubuntu is a useful distribution for your desktop or server, but I recommend to stay away from it on other platforms.

Comment: @Philippos The typical way of getting a compiler on a new platform is making a cross toolchain first, the using the cross toolchain to build the native compiler for that platform.

Comment: Honestly? Why? I have always used an old compiler to build the new compiler. Why adding complexity by using a cross compiler? If you need a new compiler version on your desktop, do you also use the cross compiler on your ARM machine to build it? I have better experience with native building.